# ImportError *.so: no suitable image found

Tags: python, echonest

I need to change the tempo of a song for a project and I would like to use the echonest's python library [remix](https://echonest.github.io/remix/). 
However, when I run, for example, the following command:

`python beatshift.py "01 - I Saw Her Standing There.mp3" out.mp3`

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "beatshift.py", line 19, in
>   <module>
>       from echonest.remix import audio, modify   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/echonest/remix/modify.py", line
>   11, in <module>   File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/soundtouch.py", line 7, in
>   <module>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/soundtouch.py",
>   line 6, in **bootstrap** ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/JL/.python-eggs/remix-2.4.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/soundtouch.so,
>   2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Users/JL/.python-eggs/remix-2.4.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/soundtouch.so:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture

Do you know what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Run `file /Users/JL/.python-eggs/remix-2.4.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/soundtouch.so` and tell us what it says.  Also `uname -a`.

Comment: @John Zwinck, thank you for your answer. This is what these commands say:
JL$ `file /Users/JL/.python-eggs/remix-2.4.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/soundtouch.so`:
/Users/JL/.python-eggs/remix-2.4.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/soundtouch.so: Mach-O bundle i386

`JL$ uname -a`:
Darwin JLs-MacBook-2 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Somehow you got a 32-bit `i386` shared library on your 64-bit `x86_64` system.  `file` on an `.so` should usually say `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`.  Where did you get that `i386` shared library?

Comment: I downloaded echonest's remix library from [here](https://github.com/echonest/remix). and I have followed the instructions in the INSTALL.txt file.